# Node JS - nodemailer & imap-simple - Identify threads

Tags: node.js, smtp, imap

(I feel sorry for my poor english, but i'll do my best !) :)

I'm trying to setup a local mailbox for a personnal project, and i'm trying to use imap-simple and nodemailer to do that.

I want to be able to identify a thread, when i send an e-mail.

Here's what i exactly want to do :

In my application, i'll be able to send an e-mail to a specific person (let's admit foo@bar.com)

When the mail is sent, a callback function will store mail content and subject in DB (for example, in a CRM app, i will store the sent mail which will be related to a specific record in my database).

The complex part is just after that :

When the person replies to this e-mail, i want using IMAP to identify that this person is answering to my previous mail, and then store it in DB too, also linked to the same record i used on my first e-mail.

I actually have this in a sandbox folder (For IMAP) :

```
var imaps = require('imap-simple');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var config = {
    imap: {
        user: 'catchall@xxxxxxxx.fr',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx',
        host: 'imap.gmail.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
        authTimeout: 3000
    }
};

imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {

    return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
        var searchCriteria = [
            'UNSEEN'
        ];

        var fetchOptions = {
            bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
            markSeen: false,
        };
        console.log('Passing there');
        return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {
            var subjects = results.map(function (res) {
                return res.parts.filter(function (part) {
                    return part.which === 'HEADER';
                })[0].body.subject[0];
            });
            console.log('BASE');
            console.log(results[0]);
            console.log('FIRST');
            console.log(results[0].parts[0]);
            console.log('SECOND');
            console.log(results[0].parts[1]);
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the SMTP part :

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
           user: 'catchall@xxxxxxxx.fr',
           pass: 'xxxxxxxx'
       }
});

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'catchall@xxxxxxxx.fr', // sender address
    to: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Subject of your email', // Subject line
    html: '<p>Here is my test !</p>',// plain text body
    headers: {
        'collection': 'Pipelines',
        'doc-ID': 'mydocid'
    }
};

transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
    }
});

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log(info);
});
```

Here is a screen of what i want to be able to :

[image: Example]

On **IMAP**, i'm getting exactly the information i want in console :

```
BASE
{ attributes:
   { date: 2019-12-05T16:53:07.000Z,
     flags: [],
     uid: 94,
     modseq: '27800',
     'x-gm-labels': [ '\\Important' ],
     'x-gm-msgid': '1652099423356172171',
     'x-gm-thrid': '1652099362185438260' },
```

**x-gm-thrid** allow me to identify a thread. Perhaps, i can't find this information in the nodemailer callback function :

```
Server is ready to take our messages
{ accepted: [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 400,
  messageTime: 819,
  messageSize: 346,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK  1575566223 m3sm12955793wrs.53 - gsmtp',
  envelope:
   { from: 'catchall@xxxxxxxxxx.fr',
     to: [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '<f93b3970-e17a-84b5-d0d1-ebb4fd6efe46@xxxxxxxxxx.fr>' }
```

Does anyone have an idea of how i could proceed ?

**Thanks a lot btw !**

Happy coding :)

Comment: can you change it to `function (err, info) {..}` to `function (err, info, response) {..}` and check what is coming from the `response` param. Also, `x-gm-*` is gmail specific header. It is not returned by nodemailer

Comment: Your outgoing messages should contain a `message-id` field. The responses will contain either `in-reply-to`, `references` or both containing the message-id of your *outgoing* message, so you can correlate outgoing messages with responses easily.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty , i tried response argument, but there is apparently nothing in it :/  @amt , ok i see, do you know if this is present on any message, without any specific field as said @AritraChakraborty for `x-gm-*` ? I'll try this and see

Answer (score 2):

For those who will read this post, here the answer, thanks to @arnt,

As @arnt said, there is for IMAP protocol, a `reference` attribute which is storing the previous message ID stored in `results[0].parts[1]` :

```
references: [ '<23df0af1-8ff1-0ffa-091e-a645a38e4a67@foobar.fr>' ],
     'in-reply-to': [ '<23df0af1-8ff1-0ffa-091e-a645a38e4a67@foobar.fr>' ],
```

This one is also available when you send a message, in `info` :

```
  envelope:
   { from: 'foobar@foobar.fr',
     to: [ 'foobar@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '<23df0af1-8ff1-0ffa-091e-a645a38e4a67@foobar.fr>' }
```

This way, we're able to correlate mail conversation.

Thanks a lot for help :)

Topic closed